# Which WCF extensibility point can I use, to get list of operation names & its method signature?

Tags: c#, wcf

As the title says, I need to list down method names & Request & response type (local name only not fully qualified name). I was evaluating various alternative. Here are my findings-

1. Parameter Inspector: Have access to operation name, but not to request & response type for each operation.

   ```
   public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
   {
       foreach (ClientOperation operation in clientRuntime.Operations)
       {                
           operation.ParameterInspectors.Add(new ParamInfo());
       }
   }
   ```
2. Message Inspector: Can't be used since they are xml representation of message.
3. Message Formatters: Unfortunately our WCF service uses, `XmlSerializer` :-( this extensibility will not be triggered.

What is the way to go forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MethodInfo that you are looking for is hiding in the ServiceEndpoint. For example assuming there's a synchronous operation defined:

```
endpoint.Contract.Operations[0].SyncMethod.ReturnType
```

or

```
endpoint.Contract.Operations[0].SyncMethod.GetParameters()
```

What makes this a little confusing is that ServiceEndpoint is dealing with the .NET implementation of the contract parameters and not the SOAP messages. In other words if you implement your service to use asynchronous communication or tasks its a different property on the [OperationDescription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.operationdescription.aspx).